# Regular expression help in Python. Looking for an expression for RGB values

Tags: python, regex, rgb

Looks like I need a little help with a regular expression to match RGB values.  I've built the following expression but it doesn't find a match.  It is also insufficient because I need to expand it to check for three digits and only a 0-255 value should exist.

For example. The following are all valid values I need to match against:

```
0,0,0
0, 0, 0
255,255,255
255, 255, 255
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
expression = re.compile(r'(\\d+),(,),(\\d+),(,),(\\d+)')
expression.match(text)
```

Comment: I've posted an answer, but I'd also like to point out that you seem to be confused about the purpose of raw strings.  The fact that you're using a raw string means that you can say `"\d"` instead of `"\\d"`.  Check the [Python regex docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#raw-string-notation) for a more in depth explanation.

Comment: Ya, I forgot to strip those the extra back-slash out.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *can* insure that the numbers are between 0 and 255 with a regex, but I highly recommend against it.  An easier method here is to capture the numbers with a regex and check that they are between 0 and 255 by simply casting to an int and comparing:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = r"(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)"
>>> re.match(r, "0, 254,10").groups()
('0', '254', '10')
>>> all(0 <= int(group) <= 255 for group in re.match(r, "0, 254,10").groups())
True
>>> all(0 <= int(group) <= 255 for group in re.match(r, "0,256, 190").groups())
False
```

Comment: Nice one, Nolen! Anything to avoid a 255 regex soup. :)

Comment: @zx81 what, you don't like `r"(\d|\d\d|0\d\d|1\d\d|(?:2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5])))\s*,(\d|\d\d|0\d\d|1\d\d|(?:2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))),\s*(\d|\d\d|0\d\d|1\d\d|(?:2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5])))"`? :p

Comment: I love it, in fact I'm married to it. That's why I don't want to see it fooling around. :)